# How can we conclude that $q$ is indefinite?

Tags: matrices, analysis, positive-definite

I want to prove the following criterion for definite matrices of quadratic form: $$g(h)=h^T\cdot A\cdot h, \ \ \ h\in \mathbb{R}^2, \ \ \ \ \ A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b \\ b & c\end{pmatrix}\in \mathbb{R}^{2\times 2} , \  \ \ \ \ D:=ac-b^2$$

1. If $D<0$ then $q$ is indefinite.
2. If $D>0$ and $a>0$ then $q$ is positive definite.
3. If $D>0$ and $a<0$ then $q$ is negative definite.

$$$$

We have that $$aq(h)=(ah_1+bh_2)^2+Dh_2^2$$

Consider the first one. There we have $D<0$. How can we conclude that $q$ is indefinite? Could you give me a hint?

Comment: With $h_2=0$ one gets $(ah_1)^2>0$. With $(h_1,h_2)=(-bh,ah)$ one gets $Dh_2^2<0$.

Comment: Can we conclude from that that we have eigenvalues of different signs, and so the matrix is indefinit? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: @MaryStar The bilinear form will be indefinite then, since there are vectors $v$ and $w$ such that $q(v)<0<q(w)$. This is what being indefinite *means*.

Comment: Ah ok!! I see!! For the second one, we have that the right side is positive and since $a>$ it follows that $q(h)>0$, right? Does this mean that $q$ is positive definite? @JoséCarlosSantos

Comment: @MaryStar It looks correct.

Comment: Do you mean $q(h)$ instead of $g(h)$?

Comment: At $(h_1,h_2)=(-bh,ah)$, $h$ is something else tha the vector $h$ that we use here, right? @LordSharktheUnknown